# Lista desplegable con valor requerido Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, postgresql

Estoy trabajando sobre laravel 5.5

Tengo estas listas:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_uso', 
                   'Uso', 
                   [0 => 'Escoge una opción'] + App\Usos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), 
                   null, 
                   ['required','id' => 'listaUsos', 'class'=>'chosen']) !!}

{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
                   'Servidor padre: Escojer unicamente los que esten marcador con - 1', [0 => 'Escoge una opción'] +
                   App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(hostname, ' - ', id_uso) AS hostname_version"), "id")-> pluck('hostname_version', 'id')->toArray(),       
                   null, 
                   ['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
```

El problema es que al momento de guardar, toma este valor [0 => 'Escoge una opción'], Y Necesito que sea requerido que escoja un valor de la lista, en vez de tomar 'Escoge una opción', les puse el required, pero no funciona.

Alguien me podria ayudar ?

Gracias por leer, feliz día.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otro compañero de la comunidad me ayudo a resolver el problema en un comentario de otra pregunta.

A esta lista desplegable:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
                   'Servidor padre: Escojer unicamente los que esten marcador con - 1', [0 => 'Escoge una opción'] +
                   App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(hostname, ' - ', id_uso) AS hostname_version"), "id")-> pluck('hostname_version', 'id')->toArray(),       
                   null, 
                   ['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
```

le quité esta parte para que no me la tomara como primera opción:

```
[0 => 'Escoge una opción'] +
```

Y Le adicione

```
['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!} <-----
```

Para que me tomara el required, y el placeholder para enviar el mensaje de que deberia escoger un objeto de la lista, sin que ese texto se tome como un valor.

Agradezco a todos su atención, Mil gracias.

Comment: Esto funcionará en el cliente, pero para la validación en el servidor es importante _(tome en cuenta mi respuesta, además de que exista el id en su tabla relacionada, exists:mitabla,id)_  ya que no todas las peticiones pueden venir desde su interfaz,  Saludos.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, agradezco mucho tu opinion, lo voy a revisar, mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tener en tu validación, dentro de tu `FormRequest` o donde valides los datos. aparte de la regla `required` la regla `not_in:0` para evitar el primer elemento del `select`

```
'id_padre' =>'required|not_in:0',
'id_uso' =>'required|not_in:0'
```